# KnockoutValidation not working as expected

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

Looking at the documentation it looks like I should be using `validatedObservable` like this:

```
ko.validatedObservable({ id: id, name: ko.observable(name).extend({required: true}) });
```

But, the following line in the `ko.validatedObservable` definition is causing an error:

```
    obsv.errors.subscribe(function (errors) {
        obsv.isValid(errors.length === 0);
    });
```

If I wrap the inner object in an observable it works.

```
ko.validatedObservable(ko.observable({ id: id, name: ko.observable(name).extend({required: true}) }));
```

I can't reproduce the error on jsFiddle, but here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/6YMsG/. I'm using Knockout 3.0 and the latest Knockout-Validation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to repro the exception with configuring the validation plugin with setinng the `observable` option to `false`. ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pg96n/)).

Although it is not written in the documentation but you need to set `observable: true` (by the way this is the default setting) in order to the `ko.validatedObservable` work correctly:

So change your config to

```
ko.validation.init({
        grouping: {
            observable: true,
        }
    });
```

Writting `ko.validatedObservable(ko.observable({ id: id, name: ko.observable(name).extend({required: true}) }));` does not solves this problem only hides it (in my opinion this behavious is in fact a bug in the plugin).

Because in your example:

```
self.id = 1;
self.name = ko.observable("blah").extend({required: true});
self.myCheck = ko.validatedObservable(ko.observable({id: self.id, name: self.name)});
```

the validation on name will still work but your `myCheck` won't because it won't have the errors property so `<span data-bind="text: myCheck.errors"></span>` will be always empty.

Comment: Thanks! I added it to my settings: `ko.validation.init({ grouping: { deep: true, observable: true })` and it seems to work now, but if `observable: true` is the default, why do I need to set it?

Comment: If you have used `ko.validation.init({ grouping: { deep: true })` alone then because you have left out the `observable` property you have implicitly set it to `false`.